# Ticking in engine

Tags: engine, noise, jeep

I have a 2004 Jeep Grand Cherokee Laredo and there is a ticking sound in my engine. I think it’s tied to the rpm but it goes away when accelerating. If I let off the gas it comes back. Also if I put the car in neutral and rev it goes faster and louder with the rpm. I just had all my oil replaced last week and it still didn’t go away. What is it?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! While you had your oil replaced, did you ensure there's enough in it now?

Comment: Sounds like a hydraulic lifter issue, but not knowing what engine you have it's hard to say with certainty.

Comment: I have a 2004 Jeep Grand Cherokee Laredo 4.0L 6 cylinder SUV

Comment: check for cracks in your exhaust manifold. it can sound like ticking. do you smell any exhaust in the engine compartment?